# tensorflow-serving in kube uses more memory on larger kube workers

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

We run tensorflow serving in kubernetes.  We increased the kubernetes node instance size from 16x64 to 32x128 and found that tensorflow serving container started to use more memory (more than the limit it was set).  Cordoning those instances and forcing TFS back to the smaller nodes resolved the problem, comes back when we uncordon and TFS pods move to larger instances.

We set both CPU and memory requests and limits.  These models are not using GPUs.

When tensorflow is starting up on the old instances we see:

`Note: NumExpr detected 16 cores but "NUMEXPR_MAX_THREADS" not set, so enforcing safe limit of 8.`

on the new instances:

`Note: NumExpr detected 32 cores but "NUMEXPR_MAX_THREADS" not set, so enforcing safe limit of 8.`

[That code](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/blob/b68de57bfed90684b3ea79060c3a7953b9629429/numexpr/utils.py#L119-L164) seems to be doing what it says it does, and also respecting `OMP_NUM_THREADS`.

Originally we were only setting environment variables:

```
        - name: TENSORFLOW_INTRA_OP_PARALLELISM
          value: "4"
        - name: TENSORFLOW_INTER_OP_PARALLELISM
          value: "4"
```

We tried setting:

```
        - name: OMP_NUM_THREADS
          value: "6"
```

and `--rest_api_num_threads=4`, but neither made any difference at all.  These are the only "based on the cores" settings I can find.